# Create List<T> by Type

Tags: c#

I have a problem by casting a generic list. I get the value of a generic list and want to use it as a parameter for the `SomeMehtod`.

```
List<MyClass> GenericList;
var propList= this.GetType().GetProperty("GenericList").GetValue(this);

SomeMethode(propList) <-- Does not work
private void SomeMethode(List<T> genericList)
{
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint? I have tried this but it won't work:

```
List<typeof(MyClass)> newPropList = propList;
```

My Problem is that `MyClass` is stored in type variable:

```
var typesWithMyAttribute =
    from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from t in a.GetTypes()
    let attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XMLDataAttribute), true)
    where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
    select new { Type = t, Attributes = attributes.Cast<XMLDataAttribute>() };

foreach (var a in typesWithMyAttribute)
{
    var propList = this.GetType().GetProperty(a.Type.Name + "List").GetValue(this);
    SomeMethode<a.Type>(propList); <-- Won't work
}
```

Comment: Could you give a [mcve]? It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve and what error you get. ("Does not work" isn't nearly as helpful as an actual error message.)

Comment: `propList` is an `object`, you should cast it first.

Comment: You should pass it as an `IList` instead of a `List<T>`. You don't know the `T`. But you know it should be a `List<>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use reflection to get a `MethodInfo` for the *constructed* method `SomeMethod`.

```
MethodInfo genericMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethode", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
foreach (var a in typesWithMyAttribute)
{
    MethodInfo constructedMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(a.Type);
    var propList = this.GetType().GetProperty(a.Type.Name + "List").GetValue(this);
    constructedMethod.Invoke(this, new[]{propList});
}
```

For [`GetMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9(v=vs.110).aspx) you may need to specify more `BindingFlags` if your `SomeMethode` is `static` and/or `private`.

[`MakeGenericMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a `MethodInfo` appyling the type arguments to the generic `MethodInfo`.

Then you [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) that method passing your `propList` as argument.

---

Note that you have to declare `SomeMethode` as generic, too:

```
private void SomeMethode<T>(List<T> genericList)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method must be generic, as well.

```
private void SomeMethode<T>(List<T> genericList)
{
}
```

That's all I can help you with at the moment, since I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Care with the same answer I got -1 :p